# How check if login with Adminstrator account is enabled?

Tags: windows, delphi, authentication, delphi-xe5, administrator

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loU9qJd28hM) show how enable/disable Administrator login account:

1. Start *cmd.exe* as Administrator
2. `net user Administrator /active:yes` - **Enable**
3. `net user Administrator /active:no` - **Disable**

I want know if there is possibility of verify programatically if this already enabled or no?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the Win32 [`NetUserGetInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netusergetinfo) function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, what resource of `NetUserGetInfo()` indicates if *Administrator* account is enabled/disabled to login?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the various `USER_INFO_XXX` structs? Many of them will tell you whether the user account is an admin account, and if the account is disabled.

Comment: OK, solved! thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working after suggestions left in comments above and following [**this**](http://www.devpia.com/MAEUL/Contents/Detail.aspx?BoardID=50&MAEULNO=20&no=954011&ref=954011&page=1) example.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  ShellAPI,
  SysUtils;

type
  TUserInfo1 = record
    usri1_name: PWideChar;
    usri1_password: PWideChar;
    usri1_password_age: Cardinal;
    usri1_priv: Cardinal;
    usri1_home_dir: PWideChar;
    usri1_comment: PWideChar;
    usri1_flags: Cardinal;
    usri1_script_path: PWideChar;
  end;

  PUserInfo1 = ^TUserInfo1;

function NetUserGetInfo(servername: PWideChar; username: PWideChar; level: Cardinal; var bufptr: PUserInfo1): Cardinal; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll' name 'NetUserGetInfo';

function IsAdminLoginEnabled: Boolean;
const
  UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = $0002;
  username = 'Administrator';
var
  ui1: PUserInfo1;
begin
  Result := False;
  if NetUserGetInfo(nil, username, 1, ui1) = 0 then
    Result := (ui1.usri1_flags and UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) <> UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE;
end;

const
  CmdExePath = 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe';
  AdminLoginEnable = '/C net user Administrator /active:yes';
  AdminLoginDisable = '/C net user Administrator /active:no';

begin
  try
    ShellExecute(0, nil, CmdExePath, AdminLoginEnable, nil, SW_HIDE);
    Sleep(2000);
    Writeln(IsAdminLoginEnabled);
    ShellExecute(0, nil, CmdExePath, AdminLoginDisable, nil, SW_HIDE);
    Sleep(2000);
    Writeln(IsAdminLoginEnabled);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;

end.
```

Comment: Using api to disable the admin account would be a better solution in the first place as you would get a proper error (or success) result. There are many ways where calling a commandline (net user) can fail: e.g. administrator account has been renamed or localised or you don't have permission to disable it. The builtin administrator account has a well known sid that can be used together with api to enable/disable it...

Comment: The account "Administrator" could have been deleted, too - you have to examine existing accounts instead of assuming a mint installation in English. Just like the Windows directory can have a different name and C: is not automatically the system root...